# Code for randomly sized repeating multi gradients

Tags: c++, function, generator, gradient

I am trying to code a function that will generate random, variably-sized gradients to create something like this:

[image: http://www.richardrosenman.com/storage/multigradient.jpg]

I am using a language similar to C++.

Can anyone post pseudo-code to show how I can achieve something similar to this? I whipped this up in Photoshop in 5 minutes to illustrate what I'm looking for so don't take it too literally. The point is to generate randomly-sized gradients that hook up to one another.

Thanks in advance!

-Rich

Comment: Declare an array of floats. Put same variable in all elements. Then put some different variables in several elements. Then diffuse the numbers accross the neighbours(for 30-40 times with a small diffusion rate). Then plot the data on each row of pixels accross the screen. For random indices of different numbers, you can use the time seed.

Comment: Any other suggestions without the use of arrays?

Comment: Start from left, randomize the next stop length. Randomize the gradient step heigth. When reached tonext stop, start decreasing. When reached to black, start another randomized gradient. When reached end of screen, copy the line you just drawn, paste to every line below of that. You dont need to reach black, but maybe another randomized floor.

Comment: Maybe sin, cos functions joined together...

Comment: Any code examples anyone?